# Why does my 100% width in CSS HTML create a horizontal scroll bar even though I made padding and margins 0?

Tags: html, css, scroll, margin, padding

For some reason my CSS results in a horizontal scroll bar even thought there is zero padding and margins and I have made no CSS changes in my HTML.  I have read through a lot of different articles but most of them just say to get rid of margins and padding but I looked through my code multiple times and could not find any margins or padding that would cause this.  Please help:

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'MYRIADPROREGULAR';
    src: url('fonts/MYRIADPROREGULAR.eot');
    src: local('MYRIADPROREGULAR'), 
    url('fonts/MYRIADPROREGULAR.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('fonts/MYRIADPROREGULAR.ttf') format('truetype');
}
/* use this class to attach this font to any element i.e. <p class="fontsforweb_fontid_4410">Text with this font applied</p> */
.fontsforweb_fontid_4410 {
    font-family: 'MYRIADPROREGULAR' !important;
}


*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

body{

background:#55b14a;
}

.container{ 
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
    font-family: 'MYRIADPROREGULAR' ;
    font-weight: 250;
}
.container h1{
    width:95%;
    float:left;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: normal;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-left:-20px;
        margin-bottom:-10px;
} 
.container h4{
    width:85%;
    float:left;
    font-size:17px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-left:-15px;
}

.center_box{
        background:#55b14a;
                width:80%;
        margin-top:35px;
        margin-left:10px;
        margin-right:10px;
        display:block;

}
.center_box ul li{
    float:left;
    width:52px;
    height:52px;
    display:block;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
.use_coupon{
    display:block;
    width:130px;
    height:26px;
    line-height:26px;   
}
.use_coupon a{
    text-align:center;
} 



.container h4{
    margin-top: 24px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 50;
}




/* SQUARED FOUR */
/*
.squaredFour {
    width: 20px;    
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}
*/
.squaredFour label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;

    width:52px;
    height:52px;
    /*
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 0;

    border-radius: 4px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    */

    background:url('images/checkbox_bg.png');
    /*
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
    */
}

.squaredFour label:after {
/*
//  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
//  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
*/
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;

    /*background: transparent;*/ 
    top: -15px;
    left: 4px;
    border: none;
    width: 47px;
    height: 60px;
/*
 * width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
        */
}

/*
.squaredFour label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
*/

.squaredFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    background:url('images/right.png');

}

.squaredFour .style_check {
    display:none;
}


/* changes :: 16-05-2015 */

.use_coupon{
    background:#A6A6A6;
    border:1px solid #555;
    width:130px;
    height:26px;
    line-height:26px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:21px auto 18px;
}
.use_coupon a{
    font-size:11px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;  
}
h4.using_times{
    font-size:18px;
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it in JSFiddle?

Comment: This shouldn't help, but there is a chance it could, hence why I am not posting it as an answer:

`.container {...Other styles.....; box-sizing: border-box;}`

Comment: Can you add the HTML too?